# Can someone explain why this ffmpeg command worked?

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, ffmpeg, recording

I was trying to record audio from my webbrowser using ffmpeg. I tried this simple command that I thought should work.

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i default output.wav
```

But output.wav had no audio. I tried a bunch of other settings before trying vokoscreen, which I know worked from experience. When I launched vokoscreen from my shell, I saw the ffmpeg command printed to stdout. It was long and full of video options that I didn't care about, so I pruned it to the following command, and my computer's audio recorded perfectly.

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i alsa_output.usb-Schiit_Audio_Schiit_Modi_3-00.iec958-stereo.monitor audio.flac
```

I don't know how this works, or why the input to the `-i` flag is as it is. That isn't a file on my system, nor is it displayed by `arecord -l` or `arecord -L`.

Why does this audio device work, and how do I find it without using vokoscreen?

Comment: Looks like the default ALSA device is the wrong input. Use the input shown by vokoscreen.

Comment: run `pacmd list-sources`, you can use index of source `-f pulse -i 0` or `-f pulse -i 1` instead of name of source

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks, Ivan. If you post that as the answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment made by Баяр Гончикжапов, the input file url is allowed to be one of the sources listed by the command `pacmd list-sources`. pacmd is a program that can configure and query the pulseaudio server in-flight.

The value for the argument can be either the index of the device or its actual name as reported by pacmd.

If Баяр Гончикжапов posts this as an answer, I'll accept that one over mine.